# Laravel5: retrieving post_id from a hidden input returns null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a working comment form with `$post->id`  that submits data via ajax, notice there isn't any form tags.

```
<div class="comment-fields">
    <div class="row commenter-comment">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <textarea id="commenter_comment" name="commenter_comment" class="form-control comment-field" title="User's comment" placeholder="Comment Text"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row commenter-name-email">
        <input type="hidden" id="commenter_parent" name="commenter_parent" class="commenter-parent" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" id="commenter_post" name="commenter_post" class="commenter-post" value="{{ $post->id }}">
    </div>

    <div class="row commenter-captcha">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success post-this-comment">Comment</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the javascript handler

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.post-this-comment', function(){
    var form_data = {
        'per_page': $('.comments_per_page').val(),
        'commenter_parent': $('#commenter_parent').val(),
        'commenter_post': $('#commenter_post').val(),
        'commenter_comment': $('#commenter_comment').val(),
    };

    var arr = [
        'commenter_parent',
        'commenter_post',
        'commenter_comment'
    ];

    for (var i in arr, i < arr.length, i++) {
        var elem = arr[i];
        form_data[elem] = $('#' + elem).val();
    }

// console.log(form_data); // something like => Object {per_page: "some_value", commenter_parent: "some_value", commenter_user_id: "some_value", commenter_comment: "some_value"}

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'post_this_comment',
        data: form_data,
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    request.done(comment_done_handler);
    request.fail(comment_fail_handler);
});
```

All I want to do is get the post id of the current post so I can tell the comment_list() to get me only the comments of that post.

I cannot even get the value of `commenter_post` from `comment_list()` method, I get null. But I am able to retrieve the values from other methods just fine.

so I have added a hidden field (without form tags) to a partial that retrieves the `post_id`

```
<input type="hidden" id="post_id" name="post_id" class="post-id" value="{{ $post->id }}">
```

However, when I try to get the value of that field, I always get `null`

`Comment` Model

```
public static function root_comments($postId) { // setting $postId
    return self::child_comments(0, 'desc')->where('post_id', $postId);
}
```

`CommentController`

```
protected function comment_list($per_page, Request $request) {
    $post = Input::get('post_id');
    dd($post); // returns null
    $root_comments = Comment::root_comments(1); // I am setting the postId manually here
    $root_with_replies = $this->include_replies_for($root_comments);
    $paginated_comments = $this->paginate($root_with_replies, $per_page, $request);
    return $paginated_comments;
}
```

Index() method on CommentController

```
public function index(Request $request) {
        $view_data = self::view_data($request);
        return view('eastgate.comment.leave_a_comment', $view_data);
}
```

Comment: Have you first of all verified if the `value` attributes in the rendered HTML code actually contain what you think they do?

Comment: Yes, I have. The value is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dumping the whole request object and look over the parameters in the POST or GET request, make sure your field is there, if not something might be wrong with the form.

Is that hidden field, inside an actual form that is submitted before the comments_list function is called?

Comment: I have edited the question, I may not have explained it properly.

Comment: @Halnex, that definitely makes it clearer, but that comments "form" div you posted above, where is that displayed? What page are you on when that form is generated? I would assume the page of a post?  Can you show the controller method that returns the view where that comments section would be included?  I'm just trying to figure out how comment_list is called since it's not returning a view and what data is available to its calling function, etc...

Comment: comment_fields (comment form) and comment_list are both partials and are called from the view `post/show.blade.php` - this view receives data from PostController as well. All I have is the `index()` method on CommentController which has `$view_data = self::view_data($request);`

Comment: Ah okay, so the problem in displaying comments after someone submits a comment for that post via the ajax call? We calling the URL for the comments list, but since the ID isn't carried into the request properly, it fails?

Comment: No, no submission is required here. Basically the `post_id` is stored in a hidden input `commenter_post` on `comment_fields.blade.php` - I would like to grab that and use inside `comment_list()` method so I ultimately display only the comments of the post I'm viewing.

Comment: Right, I understand you there, what I'm trying to get to is how comment_list() gets called, you said it's a partial which implies that it was pulled in via an "include" call (likely in the post/show.blade.php file), but including the partial, doesn't make $request data available, only what was pushed to the including view from controller.  The way you are trying to grab post_id (Input::get or $request->input('post_id')) will only work if there was a GET or POST request submitted to that actual URL mapped to a controller function.   Sorry if this isn't helping

Comment: I understand now. But how else can I get the post id?

Comment: Well, this is all stuff you display on the post/show.blade.php view right? Why not retrieve the related comments for that post within the show() function of the post controller and pass it down the show.blade.php view for posts, and then it would be available as a collection to your comment_list partial for display. Since you call it from the show() method in your post controller, the ID is most definitely available (since otherwise how could you fetch the post to be shown?)... Thoughts?

Comment: I'm already using this on show() method `$view_data = CommentController::view_data($request)` it's part of a package I'm using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92671/discussion-between-sean-and-halnex).

Comment: Any luck mate? Did you give it a try?

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to get it work after editing the comments migration file and adding the foreign keys, after that `$post->id` became accessible :)

Comment: @Halnex Ah, so we did hit on the problem last night, glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged Laravel-5 for the question, but are using the [Laravel 4 method of retrieving input](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#basic-input). For [Laravel 5 input retrieval](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#retrieving-input), try:

```
$post = $request->input('post_id');
```

Additionally, per the [Controller help page](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers), your route arguments should come after your other dependancies.

CommentController

```
protected function comment_list(Request $request, $per_page) {
    $post = $request->input('post_id');
    dd($post);
    $root_comments = Comment::root_comments(1);
    $root_with_replies = $this->include_replies_for($root_comments);
    $paginated_comments = $this->paginate($root_with_replies, $per_page, $request);
    return $paginated_comments;
}
```

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers Request should come first, so your comment_list should be comment_list(Request $request, $per_page)

Comment: didn't change anything, still returns null.